# The etymology of "Adam" has anything to do with "Adom," hence "dominion"?

Tags: etymology

My Sunday school teacher once talked about the origin of the word "Adam" being associated with "Adom", which takes on the meaning of "dominion". Biblically speaking, I think this unconventional explanation could be quite appealing to Christians alike, but I'm really doubtful of its validity.

As Merriam-Webster Dictionary says, Adam originated from "Middle English, from Late Latin, from Greek, from Hebrew Ādhām", meaning "man" (New Oxford American Dictionry, 2nd ed).So this is the first time I heard it explained otherwise. Any evidence of that?

Comment: The old word adom does mean (red) planet Mars too!, ha adom numerical value 56!

Comment: Did you confuse between אדון (adon) and אדום (adom) ? Where did you get this association from adom = dominion?

Comment: Are there even vowels in Hebrew's written form? As I understood it, there is a whole hermeneutical tradition in Judaism which makes use of this ambiguity to substitute different vowels, experimenting with alternative words, and suggesting an almost inexhaustible range of interpretive possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary supports the etymology given by M-W. The core meaning of *Adam* is ‘mankind’. There may be further connections with words from various languages meaning ‘earth, ground’ and ‘ruddy’. I’m not sure if it has any relevance, but *Edom* is another name for *Esau*.

There seems to be no recent etymological connection with words like *dominion*, which derives from Latin *dominium*, meaning ‘property’, and, ultimately, from *dominus*, meaning ‘lord’. There may just be the possibility that in Indo-European *dominus* had something in common with the word that produced *Adam*, but, unless someone knows better, that is speculation.

Answer (score 12):

The connection is spurious for the simple reason that Adam has its roots in Hebrew, an Afro-Asiatic Semitic language; whereas Dominion has latin roots and thus is ultimately an Indo-European word.

The etymology of *Adam* comes from the classical Hebrew word for *earth, man, soil* (Genesis 2 speaks of God forming Adam out of "the dust of the ground".) This word is related to *adamah* which means "ground" and *dam* which is the Hebrew word for blood.

*Dominion* comes from the latin word *dominus* (lord/master) which literally means "master of the house" (*domus* = home, hence the english words *domestic* and *domicile*.) Another english word which is derived from this root is *timber* — material used to build the home.

Both the Semitic origins of *Adam* and the Indo-European root *dom* are likely at least 5000 years old. There is a minority of linguists who believe that the Indo-European and Semitic language families descend from a prehistoric language ancestral to both, but I don't think this is accepted in the mainstream.

In any case, it's beyond speculative to try and connect these roots.

Answer (score 7):

*Adam* אָדָם was generally held to be related to *adom* אדום. But *adom* means "red", not "dominion".

I have no idea whether this has been disputed since, as my knowledge here comes from religious and magical writers rather than linguists, and frankly religious and magical thinkers are very bad at etymology; creating links where there are none, and adding meaning where there are mere links. (At least it's better than the guy who argued *angle* the astrological term was cognate with *angel*).

Still, *adom* אדום (red) > *adama* אדמה (red arable earth) > *Adam* אָדָם at least was a traditional etymology, whether modern thinking agrees or no.

Jumping from *adom* to *dominion* makes no more sense than linking it to the West African name *Adom*. Less really, as it's easier to see how a name from the Abrahamic religions could influence another name.

The association between Adam and *dominion* is of course Genesis:

> And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have **dominion** over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. So God created man in his image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them. And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have **dominion** over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth. (Genesis 1:26-28 KJV).

The Hebrew here is

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר  אֱלֹהִ֔ים  נַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה  אָדָ֛ם  בְּצַלְמֵ֖נוּ  כִּדְמוּתֵ֑נוּ  **וְיִרְדּוּ֩**  בִדְגַ֨ת  הַיָּ֜ם  וּבְעֹ֣וף  הַשָּׁמַ֗יִם  וּבַבְּהֵמָה֙  וּבְכָל־  הָאָ֔רֶץ  וּבְכָל־  הָרֶ֖מֶשׂ  הָֽרֹמֵ֥שׂ  עַל־  הָאָֽרֶץ׃   וַיִּבְרָ֨א  אֱלֹהִ֤ים  אֶת־  הָֽאָדָם֙  בְּצַלְמֹ֔ו  בְּצֶ֥לֶם  אֱלֹהִ֖ים  בָּרָ֣א  אֹתֹ֑ו  זָכָ֥ר  וּנְקֵבָ֖ה  בָּרָ֥א  אֹתָֽם׃  וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ  אֹתָם֮  אֱלֹהִים֒  וַיֹּ֨אמֶר  לָהֶ֜ם  אֱלֹהִ֗ים  פְּר֥וּ  וּרְב֛וּ  וּמִלְא֥וּ  אֶת־  הָאָ֖רֶץ  וְכִבְשֻׁ֑הָ  **וּרְד֞וּ**  בִּדְגַ֤ת  הַיָּם֙  וּבְעֹ֣וף  הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם  וּבְכָל־  חַיָּ֖ה  הָֽרֹמֶ֥שֶׂת  עַל־  הָאָֽרֶץ׃

Which the dictionary tells me are forms from רָדָה (radah) meaning "rule" though with a variety of different connotations, suggesting "dominion" may be too harsh a nuance, or may not, as one chooses to interpret it. Either way, it's got nothing to do with אָדָם and nothing to do with *dominium* ("to own") from which we get *dominion* ("to own and rule" [from *domus* (home), cognate *domestic*]) beyond that being a possible translation.

Comment: *Adam* meaning *earth, soil* is what I have heard.  I noted a couple of years ago an Israeli movie with "Adam" in the Hebrew title (*Adama Meshuga'at*), but the English translation for the title was "Sweet Mud".

Comment: @GEdgar Adama certainly means earth. And the associations I give about are certainly widely stated. Now, whether some expert in Hebrew etymology would agree or say that recent studies dispute it is another question. "Common knowledge" isn't always right.

Comment: אֲדוֹן עוֹלָם - Lord of the Universe.  Adon Olam.  I think people have mixed up adon with adom giving the mistaken impression of dominion.  The two are generally unrelated, though.

Comment: Linguists aren’t always much better. Remember poor Goropius who speculated that the source of all languages was his own dialect of Brabantian Flemish, and that _Adam_ comes from _hath-dam_ ‘a dam against hate’. Indeed.